# How to write and InsertInOrder method in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

Here is one of my loops that I've been trying to work with. The program takes in an input file of unsorted numbers and puts them into an array. I'm trying to write this method so it will sort then into ascending order.

```
insertInOrder( int[] arr, int count, int key   )
if (count==0)
    {
        arr[0] = key;
        return;
    }


    int i=count-1;
    while(i>=0 && key<arr[i])
    {
        arr[i]=arr[i+1];
        i=i-1;
    }
    arr[i+1]=key;
```

I also tried to use a for loop but that didn't seem to be working either

```
if(count==0)
        arr[0]=key;
    int i;
    for(i=arr[arr.length-1];i>=0 && key < arr[i]; --i)
    {
        arr[i]=arr[i+1];
    }
    key=arr[i+1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array using:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

Furthermore, you seem to be trying to change the size of the array. No wonder it doesn't work. If you want to change the size dynamically you need an ArrayList, not an array.